# NexAuth.js cannot connect to Google. Error 500

Tags: firebase, next.js, next-auth

I need some help to get me started with NextAuth.js

Following this [guide](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example) I am trying to add Google authentication with existing Next.js app. I registered an app via Firebase and got GOOGLE_ID and GOOGLE_SECRET which I set in the app. Here is my [...nextauth].js:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
export const authOptions = {
  
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),

    // ...add more providers here
  ],
};
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

.env.local file:

```
GOOGLE_ID=xxx
GOOGLE_SECRET=xxx
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
```

Then in the component I import:

```
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
```

Then I call it like this:

```
 <div className="link" onClick={signIn}>
    <p>Hello Alex Smith</p>
    <p className="font-extrabold md:text-sm">Account & Lists</p>
 </div>
```

Then weird stuff begins. Then I click on the div, I get to see button: Login With Google and URL is:http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F

When I click on it, I get Internal Server Error and URL is:http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/google

Also in terminal I see:  ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined popping up. Don't know if that is relevant.

Strangely, in Google console I see no trace of app registered in Firebase.
I tried creating OAuth client manually and getting different set of credentials, switching Google account - to no avail.

I always hit that error and cannot go further. They say NextAuth is super easy to integrate, however...

Answer (score 2):

Found the cause was do do with version of Node.
Updated it to the latest version and that fixed the issue.
Now can can log in.

Comment: I was having the same issue. The problem was that `ReadableStream` for whatever reason was not included in `Node 16.x`. Upgrading to version 18.x fixed this issue because it supported it.